„It makes him feel good/bad/uneasy/etc": Was ist die beste Weise, so etwas auszudrücken?
Ich wollte wissen, wie man aus dem Englischen etwas wie Folgendes am besten übersetzen würde:

This is something that makes people feel good

oder

The story made him feel bad

Ich denke an

Das ist etwas, was die Leute glücklich macht

aber hier fehlt das Wort „fühlen".  Sagt man das auf Deutsch einfach nicht, d.h., man lässt das Wort „fühlen" weg und verwendet nur das Adjektiv?
DeepL sagt, das die Übersetzung des zweiten Satzes ist

die Geschichte gab ihm ein schlechtes Gefühl

Und hier verwenden wir ein Nomen.  Gibt es eine übliche, allgemeine Weise solche Sätze zu formuliern?


"This is something that makes people feel good" = "Das sorgt für ein gutes Gefühl (bei den Leuten)" or simply: "Da / damit fühlen sich die Leute dann gut." I am wondering whether a translation with "glücklich machen" might not be too strong, too dramatic.

"makes him feel bad" = literally "lässt ihn sich schlecht fühlen", but that is rather not something for use in the spoken language. For a more idiomatic translation, one would like to have more context, the translation might be different depending on what exactly is "bad" (feel frightened / disgusted, feel pity, feel ashamed?). "Die Geschichte gab ihm ein schlechtes Gefühl" is possible, but it is not quite clear what it really says. I suspect, this would mean that a person feels vaguely uneasy as a reaction to hearing the story, but I think this does not quite cover the case of "feeling bad about something".



Die Frage ist auf deutsch formuliert. Die Antwort sollte es dann auch sein

Ich finde die Frage spannend, kann aber nur davon abraten, solche Beispiele mit einer festen Phrase oder zu wörtlich zu übersetzen.
Die Fallstricke sind im einzelnen:

machen ist ein Verb, das einen beschränkten Wortschatz vermuten lässt. Zwei, drei Stufen schlimmer und man landet bei Ich dich machen fühlen glücklich, was als Paradebeispiel für Schwächen in Grammatik und Wortschatz herhalten kann.
fühlen hat eine starke Konnotation zu subjektiv, d. h. man fühlt sich zwar irgendwie (z. B. Nach dem dritten Bier fühlte er sich unwiderstehlich), das muss aber nichts mit der Wirklichkeit zu tun haben.
fühlen wird gerne für übertragene Formulierungen verwendet (Sie fühlte sich wie gerädert oder er fühlte sich niedergeschlagen - hier ohnehin besser: er war niedergeschlagen), sie fühlte sich wie im siebten Himmel, bei einem Adjektiv wie glücklich ist es weder nötig noch hilfreich, weil es sowieso ein Gefühl ist.

Ein paar Übersetzungsvorschläge:

Das beglückt die Leute (klingt, obwohl richtig, leider etwas nach 19. Jahrhundert), also vielleicht besser belustigt, erheitert oder einfach unterhält.
Die Geschichte hat ihn mitgenommen/deprimiert (Entsprechend zu beglückt könnte man hier betrübt hernehmen, das leider genau so veraltet klingt).


Zunächst sollte ein (weit verbreiteter) Irrtum geklärt werden, der hier (make -> machen) ebenfalls vorliegt: das englische "to make" ist zwar dieselbe Wortwurzel wie das deutsche "machen", aber man kann nicht - zumindest nicht immer - das eine mit dem anderen übersetzen. Der Grund ist, daß "machen" auf Deutsch nur im Sinne von "produzieren, herstellen" verwendet wird, während es auf Englisch viel mehr bedeutet:

If you can make it there,
you can make it everywhere.

aus "New York, New York" bedeutet eben nicht "wenn du es dort machen kannst, dann kannst du es überall machen", sondern "to make" bedeutet hier sowas wie "es schaffen", "es erreichen".
Der Satz

The story made him feel bad

korrekt übersetzt wäre ja: Die Geschichte schaffte (es), daß er sich schlecht fühlte und das wäre zwar eine gute Übersetzung, aber schlechtes (weil unidiomatisches) Deutsch. Zumindest wäre eine solche Übersetzung nur in Ausnahmefällen angebracht.

damit fühlen sich Leute gut

oder

sorgt für ein gutes Gefühl

wie von @Alazon vorgeschlagen, sind wesentlich bessere Formulierungen, je nach (hier leider nicht genanntem) Zusammenhang könnten eventuell auch in Frage kommen:

verbreitet gute/schlechte Stimmung
verdüstert die Stimmung / hellt/lockert die Stimmung auf
statt "Stimmung": Laune, Vorahnung
erweckt Mitleid, macht traurig

Aber um das beurteilen zu können, müßte man mehr als den vorhandenen Kontext zur Verfügung haben.

Danke.  Es war (vielleicht) eine nicht so gute Frage.  Was ich feststellen wollte, war, ob man all die Sätze „make someone feel something" „direkt" auf Deutsch übersetzen könnte, d.h., wie du mit „schaffen" gemacht hast.  Trotzdem scheint es, dass das kein idiomatisches Deutsch ist, dementrsprechend muss man es „auf deutsche Weise" ausdrücken.

@Cerulean: ganz im Gegenteil, die Frage war durchaus gut! Die Antwort ist halt leider nicht so einfach, wie es auf dem ersten Blick scheint.
